# How to include two htmls into another html using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I have created a bar chart and a pie chart using d3.js separately.Now I want to call the bar chart and the pie chart into another html using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready!");
    $("#piediv").load("file:///usr/local/d3/samplepi.html"); 
    $("#bardiv").load("file:///usr/local/d3/bar.html"); 
});
```

```html
<body> 
    <div id="piediv"></div>
    <div id="bardiv"></div>
</body>
```

But I'm facing an error i.e,

> NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied
>   ...It(v),b=Zt(v),_=It(d),w=Zt(d),S=It(m),k=Zt(m),E=It(y),A=Zt(y);p.forEach(function...
>   d3.v3.min.js (line 1)

How can I get rid of this problem. Can anyone please give suggestions on this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try putting it on a server and using a http:// rather then a file path

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load a filesystem path file, instead you should use relative/absolute path.

so intead of this:

```
$("#piediv").load("file:///usr/local/d3/samplepi.html");
```

should be tried like this:

```
$("#piediv").load("/usr/local/d3/samplepi.html");
```

`"/usr/local/d3/samplepi.html"` this would be your relative path with the folder structure you are following.

#### Note:

To see `.load()` is working you should setup a webserver because this internally uses ajax to load in.

Comment: Can u suggest a link regarding iframes

Comment: i have not suggested you iframes.

Comment: Can u plz tell how to write an iframe for each html

Answer (score 1):

use 2 iframes? 1 for each html. Style the iframes with your css as needed.

```
<body>
    <iframe src="graph1.html"></iframe>
    <iframe src="graph2.html"></iframe>
</body>
```